# How to specify dask client via environment variable

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

How can I instruct dask to use a distributed `Client` as the scheduler, **externally** from the code, e.g. via an environment variable?

The motivation is to take advantage of one of the key features of dask - namely the transparency of going from a single machine to a distributed cluster. However, there seems to be one little thing obscuring this transparency - the need to register a `Client` via code.

I can set the named schedulers (e.g. "synchronous" and "processes") via the config (file/env var) as [instructed here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html#configuring-the-schedulers), but how do I use the same mechanism with a distributed one?

Ideally, I would like to set something like:

```
DASK_SCHEDULER=distributed(scheduler_file=...)
```

as an environment variable which would be equivalent of running `client = Client(scheduler_file=...)` **within** python code.

This would then mean the **EXACT** same code can be run in different environments (local and distributed).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be do add to pass the scheduler  has an argument; per say using [Argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).
Thus you could have `python my_script.py <ip:port>` were you specify either the distributed  or <127.0.0.1:port> for local.